# Wordpress links don't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a newbie in Wordpress and have just started to use it and I have a problem.
I changed permalinks settings
[image]
and in admin panel links of pages changed too
[image]
but when I click on link in menu `http://mysite/services/`, I get 404 error instead of page.
What's wrong?  Do I need to change any other settings?
I use local server [Winginx](http://winginx.com/).

Comment: Have you tried going to `localhost/mysite/services` ? if that works just change the permalink to there.

Comment: If you're using Apache as the web server, make sure mod_rewrite is enabled https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs if mod_rewrite function is not probably working on the server, in this case you can simply overwrite this issue by manually editing the .htaccess file. It should look like this:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: I use nginx local server, so I tried to convert your code, using converter [http://winginx.com/en/htaccess](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) and then added it in `server` section of `nginx.conf` file, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache2, try to see if mod_rewrite is enabled. Else if you're using Nginx, try some of their configs for Nginx. https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx